# The relationship between Phonegap's "onBodyLoad()/onDeviceReady()" functions and Jquery's "$(document).ready()"

Tags: jquery, android, mobile, cordova

I am using PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile in Android, I am confused about the Phonegap's  "onBodyLoad()/onDeviceReady()" functions and Jquery's "$(document).ready()".

In PhoneGap documents:

> PhoneGap consists of two code bases:
>   native and JavaScript. While the
>   native code is loading, a custom
>   loading image is displayed. However,
>   JavaScript is only loaded once the DOM
>   loads. This means your web application
>   could, potentially, call a PhoneGap
>   JavaScript function before it is
>   loaded.
>
> The PhoneGap deviceready event fires
>   once PhoneGap has fully loaded. After
>   the device has fired, you can safely
>   make calls to PhoneGap function.
>
> Typically, you will want to attach an
>   event listener with
>   document.addEventListener once the
>   HTML document's DOM has loaded.

In jQuery doc:

> While JavaScript provides the load
>   event for executing code when a page
>   is rendered, this event does not get
>   triggered until all assets such as
>   images have been completely received.
>   In most cases, the script can be run
>   as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been
>   fully constructed. The handler passed
>   to .ready() is guaranteed to be
>   executed after the DOM is ready, so
>   this is usually the best place to
>   attach all other event handlers and
>   run other jQuery code. When using
>   scripts that rely on the value of CSS
>   style properties, it's important to
>   reference external stylesheets or
>   embed style elements before
>   referencing the scripts.
>
> In cases where code relies on loaded
>   assets (for example, if the dimensions
>   of an image are required), the code
>   should be placed in a handler for the
>   load event instead.

My experiments shows that ready() is always earlier that onDeviceReady(), how to explain this? How should I use them? Should I put ready() in onDeviceReady() to make every call safe?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`$(document).ready` will always fire first because it is triggered when all the DOM elements have loaded.  Images, javascript functions, css, etc. may not have loaded by this time.

So PhoneGap has you put the `onload` method on the body's `onLoad` method so that it fires when that particular part of the DOM is ready.  Once the DOM is prepared, you create an event listener to ensure that phonegap.js *itself* is ready (and not just the application UI, for example).  Only after phonegap.js is loaded can you use the functions that it provides.

So yes, `$(document).ready` will fire first, but that does not mean that you can use phonegap.js (the 'api' calls).  You cannot put `$(document).ready` inside of another function (as far as I know), since it is triggered by the DOM being loaded.  You *can* (but should not) however call your `onDeviceReady` function from `$(document).ready`.  The problem with this is that if the device is NOT in fact ready, the api calls will not be made.

So I would continue to use the body onLoad/onDeviceReady chain they have set up.  Let me know if this needs more elaboration.

Comment: could you elaborate on this for when there is a single code base for desktop browser, mobile browser and native application.  is there a working example for this?