# .live("pageshow"..) not working on Phonegap JQuery Mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have following code that uses JQuery Mobile. Point here is that I want some code to be executed when 'pageshow' event is triggered.

All code below works nicely on Chrome. I can see console logs. However when I run this as part of Phonegap application I never get 'pageshow' event triggered.

Have been investigating this for some time now without success. Hopefully someone could explain me why my event is missing and what are needed steps to get this code working on Phonegap.

**details.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">      </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
        <!-- cordova -->
        <script src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="details_page">
      <a href="places.html" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
      <h3>Hi I am second page</h3>
    </div>

    <script src="js/details.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**details.js**

```
$("#details_page").live("pageshow", function() {
    console.log('I am alive! (details.html)');
});
```

Comment: i tried and the event is triggered..are you sure you are not missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the following

```
$(document).delegate("#details_page", "pageshow", function() {
    console.log("Hello world!");
});
```

Also note that you can only run code after the deviceready event has been fired.

So with the device ready event it would be like so :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    $(document).delegate("#details_page", "pageshow", function() {
        console.log("Hello world!");
    });
}
```

Hope this helps, 
Mike

Comment: My application is structured from three html files and corresponding javascript files. So I am listening for device ready. However that is done in index.js, javascript file for my start page. When I add $(document).delegate there for it gets called. However I don't like the fact that this way I need to register listeners in index.js even though rest of the logic is in details.js. What would be right paradigm to use here?

Comment: Well, you'll need to be using one general wrapper for all underlying pages, as jQM loads all pages into the DOM.
It happens like so :
- First of all jQuery loads your index.html into the DOM
- If a user change pages it loads everything up in the DOM but only the element between the <div data-role="page"> tags, which causes your javascript to **not** function.
An other option is adding rel="external" but this clears the DOM and reload the full page.
Hope this helps,
Regards

Comment: Thank you NDakotaBE :) This explanation helped me to understand what the problem was. I moved <scrtipt src="js/details.js" /> inside <div data-role="page"> and now it is loaded when page loads. I am coming from obj-c background and query mobile is new thing to me. This cleared up lot of questions I have been having.

Comment: Just note that adding the script tag in the page div, isn't actually correct. Glad I could help

Comment: Thanks for this info also. Will do general wrapper approach if that is right way to go with jquery mobile.

Answer (score 3):

you may have solved it by now, but for those stumbled upon this as I did, here is what I've found to solve.
live.() has been deprecated in JQuery 1.7 and removed since 1.9.
Use on.() instead.
I've changed my (ex.) line from:

```
$('#detailsPage').live('pageshow', function(event) {
```

to:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#detailsPage', function(event) {
```

HTH,
rash*

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be that you're calling the JS after the page has been shown.

If that's the problem you just need to put

```
<script src="js/details.js"></script>
```

in the head or before the "page" div

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. I tried this but doesn't seem to make difference on Phonegap.