# phonegap does not trigger jquery click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-click-event

The example is here http://jsfiddle.net/V3qb9/57/. It runs perfectly on desktop and jsfiddle -- whenever I change the radio button, an alert is popped up. But when I try it on phonegap, the click event is not triggered at all. Any thoughts why?

Comment: I tried your code and it is working for Cordova 1.9.0… Show us some code so that we can help you….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried your code in the init method used by phonegap in body onload tag `<body onload="init();">` and i was able to see the alert.

i used the example that comes with phonegap 1.9.0 for android.

i tested it on my phone (Jelly Bean).

Answer (score 1):

Are you correctly binding the the action on Device ready?  I don't think $(document) works in Phonegap the way it does in a browser.  According to this answer:

[The relationship between Phonegap's "onBodyLoad()/onDeviceReady()" functions and Jquery's "$(document).ready()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036703/the-relationship-between-phonegaps-onbodyload-ondeviceready-functions-and)

try this instead:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        alert("PhoneGap is now loaded!");
    }, false);
}, false);
```

Comment: I did put that function into deviceready(), but it didn't work. You may want to try it...

Answer (score 1):

use

```
/* enter code here */ function onBodyLoad()
{       
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}function onDeviceReady()
{
    // do your thing!
    //navigator.notification.alert("Cordova is working")
}
```

top of your script. Hope it will work