# .click() does not work in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have this function:

```
$scope.launchSelectImg = function() {
   document.getElementById("fileElem").click();
};
```

The `.click()` does not fire off in PhoneGap on my android device. Works just fine in the browser.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You have `onload="init();"` on your `<body>` tag?

Comment: I do not. What would that do for this situation and why? Just curious, I want to understand this.

Comment: I don't know. I used google and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659562/phonegap-does-not-trigger-jquery-click-event

Comment: What fixed this for me was that the element on the page had styling property of "display: none". When that was on their this would not work. I set the opacity to 0 and that worked.

Comment: If the element has display:none it would not be there to click...

Answer (score -2):

May be this will help..

```
$("#fileElem").live("click", function() 
{
   alert("success");
});
```